# change eclipse name in eclipse.exe

Tags: eclipse, icons, launcher

I consider how can I change name of eclipse.exe, which config files should I modify if I want to use other name for eclipse.exe e.g eclipse_new_version.exe instead of eclipse.exe.

I am not interested in making shortcut with other name, batch file converted to exe or using 3rd party software like launch4j.

Second question is:
Could I change icon of eclipse.exe for my favorite icon without using 3rd party software like ResourceHacker.

Comment: I found https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Updating_Branding but in older version of eclipse I could not find eclipse.ico.

Comment: Regarding name, I have eclipse.ini as hidden file. There was path pointed at correct jvm. When I changed name of eclipse I got error. I should just create myname.ini config file with appriopriate configuration